# cloning form elements and the return a template file

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am building a website, where on the click of a link you can clone the form elements, what I am wanting to know is that, when I send the `$_POST` to my controller and check that the information submitted is correct, how do I then return a template that has enough elements so that errors can be rectified, so example my original form looks like this,

```
<fieldset class="entry">
<label for="email_address">Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="email_address[]" value="" class="text small"/> 
<label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname[]" value="" class="text small"/>                     
<label for="surname">Surname</label>                            <input type="text" name="surname[]" value="" class="text small"/>
</fieldset>
```

how can I return the correct amound of fieldsets based on the $_POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this:

> How can I return the correct amount of fieldsets based on the $_POST?

If each fieldset only has one instance of each bracketed[] field name, you can just count how many were submitted (of any of the fields).

```
$number_of_fieldsets = count((array) $this->input->post('email_address'));
```

I've used `$this->input->post()` (since you're using CI) in case the value is not set (it will return false), you may use some `isset()` logic instead if you wish.

I've cast to array here in case the return value of `$this->input->post('email_address')` is false (count will return 0) or for some reason, a string (count will return 1). This is just a mild attempt at being defensive, you will probably want to handle unexpected results with your own methods.

Once again, it doesn't matter which field you choose to count.